# Best way of using generic entities in ravendb?

Tags: database-design, nosql, ravendb

I'm in a process of converting my RDBMS(oracle) to ravenBD.
Today we have 2 main tables: 1. metadata 2: entites.
The Entities table has the fallowing columns: ID, TypeId, DateSaved, String1-20, int1-20, etc.. The Metadata table has a mapping of each column to the meaning(when TypeId = 1 -> String1 = Name,
when TypeId = 2, String1 = Description).
It's a basicly a generic db, so in our server the is only 1 main object - Entity, which describs all of our entities.
Nowadays as we get larger and lager we need to suport more type of entities which have a vaster number of columns, more that we can support with that design.(and we hate to do alter table).
NoSql is classic for that need. Now I'm tring to come up with the best practice with raven for that problem...

I would realy appreciate some designs...

Raz

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow.  We expect specific, well-researched questions.  In your case, please go read the RavenDB documentation, walk through some of the samples, and try a few things out for yourself.  Then come back here when you have a specific question to ask.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
public class Entity
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public Dictionary<string, object> Values {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Ok thats what i thought... but how can i index the sub values? and i have also a spatial info to index

Comment: I'm curious to know if RavenDB indexes generic types, so for instance if I put an instance that has fields x, y, and z will queries be able to optimize for searching those fields.